# Node.js with V8 suitable for limited memory device?

Tags: node.js, v8

Would like to know is node.js with V8 engine suitable to be deployed on limited memory device (e.g. 256mb) and running in parallel with other process.

I read that it will hook up the resource of the machine. Is there way to limit the memory and processing usage of V8 engine itself?

Comment: NodeJS on Respberry Pi? This could be interesting.

Comment: Can you tell more about the device? Which CPU architecture, type of disk (solid/spinning), does it also need to run a GUI, etc.

Comment: I am running it on rooted android, it needs GUI as well. So, is best to constraint the memory.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

256 MB is sufficient amount of RAM to run Node.js (e.g. on Linux VPS instance), assuming no other memory-hog software is run. Node has --max-stack-size argument for limiting the memory usage.

Node's single-thread evented server model generally makes efficient use of resources, but V8 due its JIT architecture is likely to use somewhat more memory than interpreted/bytecompiled implementations, such as PHP or CPython (while offering superior performance). Also, to take advantage of multiple CPU cores, multiple Node.js processes must be run (versus memory-sharing threads), effectively multiplying the memory usage, but this limitation applies to its most popular competitors as well.

In the respect of *"running in parallel with other process"* or *"hooking up the resource of the machine"*, there is nothing special about running Node.js process (except the not uncommon multicore issue); it behaves similarly to any userland program. You can low-prioritize the Node.js process in OS level (e.g. with `nice`), but depending on your device/application, I/O can be potentially more an issue.

Purely from technical/effectiviness perspective, Erlang is probably more ideal choice for a high-level language when true multiprocessing support and high concurrency is required.

Answer (score 15):

64MB of RAM is sufficient for V8 and Node.js

See "[Compiling Node.js for Arduino YÚN](http://fibasile.github.io/compiling-nodejs-for-arduino-yun.html)"
and also "[installing Node.js on Arduino YÚN](http://giorgiocefaro.com/blog/installing-node-js-on-arduino-yun)".

Arduino YÚN runs linux with 64MB of RAM.

Comment: "full-stack Node.js is just too much for the Yun, and that all that can be done are only very simple scripts" see http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=193765.15

Comment: Sure, on such a device you are very limited, but that "only very simple scripts" is very relative too. In my experiment, a TL-MR3020 with half the RAM of YÚN, is doing the following:
 * serving an HTML5 web application;
 * receiving JSON messages on WebSocket Secure every 200ms;
 * sending JSON messages on WebSocket Secure every 50ms;
 * sending and receiving JSON messages on UDP every 40ms;
 * logging operations on text file.
All that works very fine with 2 or 3 clients, then it becomes a little slower with the messages.

Comment: @MatteoT. would you have a link/guide on how you set Node.js on that device; is it using OpenWRT?

Comment: I downloaded the packages built by the Arduino YUN Community and installed them on OpenWRT. I also used a USB flash drive to expand the memory of my router

Answer (score 6):

The [BeagleBone](http://beagleboard.org/static/beaglebone/latest/README.htm) has 256MB RAM (and in a normal configuration, no virtual memory), and it runs node.js quite nicely.