# Amazon Fargate vs EC2 container website hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, hosting, next.js

I got a project recently in which I have to build a React / NextJS application which will serve occasional high traffic but will mostly sit idle. We are currently looking for the cheapest option in all categories, but also want to build a scalable and manageable app with a quick and easy CI/CD pipeline. For the development server, we chose Heroku's free plan and pipeline, as I think it's perfectly idle for the job. For production, we decided to use Docker as it's the best way to set up a CD pipeline, and with 2000 minutes of free Github Actions per month, the whole Production/Development pipeline will be essentially free of cost for us. We also were thinking to use AWS because of its features and we want to keep a minimum number of bills to manage. For DB we're thinking of using DynamoDB because of free 25GB lifetime storage which will be enough as the only dynamic data in the site will be user data and blogs. And for object storage, the choice is S3.

Here, we're confused between the two offerings by AWS when it comes to Container hosting, ECS EC2, and ECS Fargate. While Fargate definitely feels like a better choice because of the fact that the application will sit idle most of the time, but we're really confused in resource provisioning for containers in Fargate. The app is running on NextJS, so it'll be server-side rendered.

So my question was, will a combo of `0.5 GB RAM x 0.25 vCPU` will be enough for a Server Side Rendered NextJS application? Or should I go for a dedicated EC2? Or another cloud provider maybe?

Answer (score 0):

NextJS is a framework that run on top of nodejs, as there is no such specific requirement ([nodejs 10 only)](https://nextjs.org/docs) mentioned on the documentation but you can treat them as we treat nodejs.

[Node.js with V8 suitable for limited memory device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613528/node-js-with-v8-suitable-for-limited-memory-device)

> So my question was, will a combo of 0.5 GB RAM x 0.25 vCPU will be
> enough for a Server Side Rendered NextJS application? Or should I go
> for a dedicated EC2? Or another cloud provider maybe?

I will not suggest EC2 type ECS service, you can go for **fargate** with minimal memory and CPU and set auto-scaling of ECS services whenever required.

But I think we have a better option then fargate that is [serverless-nextjs](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-8#serverless-nextjs)

> Serverless deployment dramatically improves reliability and scalability by splitting your application into smaller parts (also called [[lambdas](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/concepts/lambdas/)][3](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/concepts/lambdas/)). In the case of Next.js, each page in the pages directory becomes a serverless lambda.
>
> There are a [number of benefits](https://zeit.co/blog/serverless-express-js-lambdas-with-now-2#benefits-of-serverless-express) to serverless. The referenced link talks about some of them in the context of Express, but the principles apply universally: serverless allows for distributed points of failure, infinite scalability, and is incredibly affordable with a "pay for what you use" model.
> [image]

[Serverless Nextjs](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-8#serverless-nextjs)